# how to add links that can be clicked on android alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I will make dialog alerts that contain about me and I also add some social media links there but when I build the application the available links do not become clickable links.

the code example I entered like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder lihat = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        lihat.setTitle("About");
        lihat.setMessage("Aplikasi ini dibuat oleh Muhamad Faisal Halim guna memenuhi TUGAS ( Aplikasi Biodata Menggunakan SQLite)" +
                "\n\nInstagram : <a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/_faisalhalim\">Faisal Halim</a>" +
                "\nFcebook : <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/faisal.kitut\">Halim</a>" +
                "\nBlog : <a href=\"https://www.halimlab.com\">Halimlab</a>)")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Oke",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = lihat.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Then how to make the link clickable

Comment: search for clickablespans

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder lihat = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    lihat.setTitle("About");
    lihat.setMessage("Aplikasi ini dibuat oleh Muhamad Faisal Halim guna memenuhi TUGAS ( Aplikasi Biodata Menggunakan SQLite)" +
            "\n\nInstagram : <a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/_faisalhalim\">Faisal Halim</a>" +
            "\nFcebook : <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/faisal.kitut\">Halim</a>" +
            "\nBlog : <a href=\"https://www.halimlab.com\">Halimlab</a>)")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Oke",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Here is your required Button click Code
    lihat.setPositiveButton("Button name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Action perform on press button
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = lihat.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Use this Code Same for negative button and neutral button